# C CGI - How to Determine if fwrite has Finished Writing for HTML Display?

Tags: c, xampp, cgi, fwrite, lampp

I want to display the image in the HTML generated by CGI after it was successfully saved in the cgi-bin directory (it is in 777 file mode at that time).
However, it is not displayed.

[image: Problem 1]

Even though the sample image (well, GIF) is saved.

[image: Problem 2]

Here is a part of my code that I think is important:

```
//Part of main function.
FILE *myfile=fopen(POINTEROF("attach1")->filename, "wb");
fwrite(POINTEROF("attach1")->value, POINTEROF("attach1")->length, 1, myfile);
fclose(myfile);   //This works (cgi-bin is set to 'weaker' file mode i.e. chmod 777)

printf("Content-type: text/html\n\n");
puts("<!DOCTYPE html><html><body>");
printf("<image src='%s'/>", POINTEROF("attach1")->filename); //Doesn't work...
puts("</body></html>");
//Rest of the code is parsing stuff. Not relevant here...
```

How can I check if fwrite is done so that the GIF will the displayed? Thanks!

Comment: Have you tried copying the link for the created image and displaying it in another browser window?  If it does work, it might be a timing issue that caused the image not to be displayed originally.  Otherwise, it seems like a problem with how the .gif was created or with the path to the image.

Comment: Hmm... When I try _localhost/cgi-bin/Penguin.png_, it displays a server error, but when I try _/opt/lampp/cgi-bin/Penguin.png_, it works.

Comment: Permission problem? Have you looked at the server logs?